# Google ie7 code not working on site

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to use the wonderful

```
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
```

on my site, I have used it before and it worked fine but now it won't do anything on this website below
http://lukeirwin.com/

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: No, but +1 for nice design :-)

Comment: thanks, i developed it and my friend designed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make sure that the document is not in quirks mode by doing `javascript:alert( document.compatMode )` in the address bar of IE6. If it's in quirks mode, kill the whitespace before the doctype.